# Ruby Mechanize form input field text

Tags: ruby, csv, automation, web-scraping, mechanize

Resolved - the "abc = list.scan(/[([^)]+)]/).last.first" line was correct but also included the quotes, which the website search form did not accept.  Corrected it to abc = list.scan(/\"([^)]+)\"/).join.

Thanks for all the help.

---

I have to automate a search using a list of 100 keywords that is in a csv file.

With Mechanize, I can submit the search using this example (http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html):

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://google.com/')
google_form = page.form('f')
google_form.q = 'ruby mechanize'
page = agent.submit(google_form)
pp page
```

However, when I make it loop through the csv file, it returns an error (in this example, the first csv entry would be 'ruby mechanize':

```
#i have already imported the csv list, now it is looping through the array "raw_list"

raw_list.each do |list|
abc = list.scan(/\[([^\)]+)\]/).last.first

# i tested a "puts abc" which returned "ruby mechanize", so I don't understand why the rest of this doesn't work


agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://google.com/')
google_form = page.form('f')
google_form.q = abc

#even though abc = "ruby mechanize", an error occurs. 


page = agent.submit(google_form)
pp page
```

It doesn't seem to take the variable **"abc"**, but works if you manually type in **'ruby mechanize'** even though both are the same.

The error that appears is:

```
C:filename: in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:442:in `get'
from C:/Users/victor/RubymineProjects/untitled/scraper.rb:23:in `block in <top (required)>'
from C:/Users/victor/RubymineProjects/untitled/scraper.rb:19:in `each'
from C:/Users/victor/RubymineProjects/untitled/scraper.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posting the error might be helpful :)

Comment: I can't tell much without seeing line numbers. My guess is you're getting a page without a form (one of those 'we think you're a robot' pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is telling you that something on line 19 in your code is causing the issue for line 442 in mechanize.

I tried your sample out in IRB and it seems to work fine:

```
2.2.2 :001 > require 'mechanize'
 => true 
2.2.2 :002 > agent = Mechanize.new
 => #<Mechanize:...
2.2.2 :003 > page = agent.get('http://google.com/')
 => #<Mechanize::Page
  ...
2.2.2 :004 > google_form = page.form('f')
 => #<Mechanize::Form
 ...
2.2.2 :005 > google_form.q
 => "" 
2.2.2 :006 > abc = "ruby mechanize"
 => "ruby mechanize" 
2.2.2 :007 > google_form.q = abc
 => "ruby mechanize" 
2.2.2 :008 > page = agent.submit(google_form)
 => #<Mechanize::Page
 ...
```

Scan will return nil if nothing is found so your error is happening here:

```
abc = list.scan(/\[([^\)]+)\]/).last.first
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html

You can replace that with:

```
abc = list.scan(/\[([^\)]+)\]/).join
```

You'll always get a string although it may be only "".

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join